Почему не импортируется из модуля bot?

Всем привет! Пишу вот такой код:
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from bot.handlers import start, help_command, quiz, answer, score

load_dotenv()

почему возникает ошибка: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
в строке:
from bot.handlers import start, help_command, quiz, answer, score

что я не так делаю?
Уже все способы перепробовал, ничего не помогает

ошибка в этой строке: from bot.handlers import start, help_command, quiz, answer, score

Покажите какая у вас структура папок/файлов

И как код запускаете тоже может быть важно.

код запускаю из файла main.py

Либо делайте импорт from handlers import start, help_command, quiz, answer, score, либо запускайте как пакет: python -m bot.main

И вот эта строка не нужна: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))). Вам разве что может понадобиться добавить директорию выше по уровню (корень проекта) в pythonpath, если вам например из database понадобится что-то импортировать. А текущая директория файла и так всегда в pythonpath.
